# Trying to get rid of unwanted records in query

Tags: t-sql

I have the following query

```
Select * from Common.dbo.Zip4Lookup where 
zipcode='76033' and 
StreetName='PO BOX' and 
'704' between AddressLow and AddressHigh and 
(OddEven='B' or OddEven = 'E')
```

The AddressLow and AddressHigh columns are varchar(10) fields.

The records returned are

```
AddressLow   AddressHigh
------------ ------------
1            79
701          711
```

The second is the desired record How do I get rid of the first record.

Comment: What do you mean by "get rid of"??

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that SQL is using a string compare instead of a numeric compare.  This is because AddressLow/High are `varchar` and not `int`.

As long as AddressLow/High contain numbers, this should work:

```
Select * from Common.dbo.Zip4Lookup where 
   zipcode='76033' and 
   StreetName='PO BOX' and 
   704 between 
       CAST(AddressLow as INT) and 
       CAST(AddressHigh as INT) and 
   (OddEven='B' or OddEven = 'E')
```

Comment: +1; this is the way, but still I would rather retype the column to numeric if you want to use this kind of condition.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your condition fits to the first record in `7` on the beginning of the `79` because it's the string value. The easist way is IMHO change the data type to some numeric one.